# Can StreamSets Data Collector automatically create tables in the destination database?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, cdc, streamsets

Is there a way for StreamSets Data Collector to automatically create tables in the destination database based on the origin database in the case of cdc?

I am reading data from a source: mssql and writing to a destination, postgresql. If I am interested in 50 tables in the source, I do not want to manually create those tables in the destination db.

Answer (score 0):

There is a (beta) Postgres Metadata processor for StreamSets Data Collector that will create and alter tables on the fly - more information at [Drift Synchronization Solution for Postgres](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/index.html#datacollector/UserGuide/JDBC_DriftSolution/JDBC_DriftSyncSolution_title.html#concept_ljq_knr_4cb).